# Keyboard hide input in a modal

Tags: react-native, keyboard, native-base

I am using https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal in an application, with a NativeBase input field.

But when the keyboard is up, the input field disappear by going up.

I have activated the `avoidKeyboard` props on the modal but it doesn't fix my problem.

I have also tried putting `KeyboardAvoidingView` around the input field without success.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey check out this article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution, my modal is composed of 3 parts, The Header, the Content and the Footer.
As stated in my question, I have put the `avoidKeyboard` props on Modal, but the content still disappeared off screen.

The solution was to put `scrollEnabled={false}` on Content.

My code look like this now :

```
<Modal isVisible avoidKeyboard onBackdropPress={this.handleDismiss} onBackButtonPress={this.handleDismiss}>
      <View style={styles.modal}>
        <Header>
          ...
        </Header>
        <Content scrollEnabled={false} padder>
         ...
        </Content>
        <Footer>
          ...
        </Footer>
      </View>
    </Modal>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this **KeyboardAwareScrollView**

npm i react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view --save

```js
 <KeyboardAwareScrollView enableOnAndroid={true} style={{height:"100%"}}
            enableAutoAutomaticScroll={(Platform.OS === 'ios')} extraHeight={130} extraScrollHeight={130}>
                <View>
                  <FormInput />
                 </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Modal>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    behavior="position"
    enabled
  >
    {myContent}
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</Modal>
```

It works for me